# Facebook sharing image error with facebook debug

Tags: plugins, seo, facebook

I used to have Yoast as my main plugin but I have shifted to another plugin called SEO Press but then I have started having a problem that Facebook share is only fetching the resized smaller picture causing thumbnail to look small.

I want to show an uncompressed full-size image as my featured image. Currently, it is only fetching irrelevant images such as sidebar ads image, and other stuff.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by "Hotlinking" option in cPanel and then SEO plugin in my wordpress. Fixing these two things, fixed my problems too.